# Where on Vancouver Island was this photo taken?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, vancouver-island

I  was on Vancouver Island for Canada Day weekend in 2014. On Canada Day we drove back from Tofino to catch the ferry at Nanaimo.

Somewhere along the way was a river on the left side of the road.  We hopped off the road and onto the rocks, and I took this photo:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out where it was.  All I have is that I referred to it as 'cascades' but not sure if it was officially called that, and that it was on the left side of the road, heading to Nanaimo. We took the road through Port Alberni, if I remember correctly.

Can anyone locate it?

Comment: What kind of camera or phone did you take the photo with? I was surprised to find my cheap $100 phone I bought in China is adding GPS coordinates to the metadata of every photo if it can. Check yours!

Comment: @hippietrail was on my old camera, unfortunately, no GPS :) (Nikon D80)

Comment: @hippietrail however, you are a genius! I remembered I was taking photos with my Nexus 4 as well, so went and checked, and they did indeed have the geolocation, matching what i found below! So good to have confirmation :) Thanks :)

Comment: We all have IQ enhancers in our pockets now. I was the last to geniusify (-:

Comment: @MarkMayo Just yesterday I was looking at a photo I had taken on my camera (no GPS) in Google Photos, and it showed an 'estimated location', which was bang accurate. Apparently, Google knows where my phone was at the moment the photo was taken (I had it in my pocket), so it can make a very good guess at my camera's location. From Google Photos - 'Google Photos might estimate a location using information such as your Google Location History, which is stored in your Google account.'. Bit Big Brother-ish, but useful!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As is always the way, I finally asked on here and then my next search located the answer for it. The answer is [Kennedy River Cascade](http://islandnature.ca/2013/09/kennedy-river-cascade/):

> It is a popular stopping point about half way between Port Alberni and
>   Ucluelet/Tofino and a place to take a break before Highway 4 begins to
>   wind its way down to Kennedy Lake. On the west side of the Sutton
>   Pass, the Kennedy River falls down through a cascade of boulders that
>   look like they’ve been tossed there by giants. The water here has worn
>   the rock into smooth sculptures and the unique, and accessible,
>   landscape is popular with tourists.

The image on the linked page almost perfectly matches the angle of the mountains in the distance.